# What is wrong with maxx function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new here. I'm trying to answer to the following problem.

2. Write a program that generates a list of 20 random numbers between 1 and 100.
   (a) Print the list.
   (b) Print the average of the elements in the list.
   (c) Print the largest and smallest values in the list.
   (d) Print the second largest and second smallest entries in the list
   (e) Print how many even numbers are in the list.

My problem is with the question (c)

```
v=[...]

maxx=v[0]

for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
    if maxx<v[i]:
        maxx=v[i]
print(maxx)
```

i know this algorithm would resolve my problem.However i would like to understand what is wrong with my max function

```
import random 

v=[]
sum=0
avg=0
maxx=0
minn=0

def generate(v):
    for i in range(0,20): 
        x=random.randint(1,100) 
        v.append(x)
    return v 
print(generate(v))

def soma(sum):
    for k in range(0,len(v)): 
        sum=sum+v[k] 
    return sum

def average(avg):
    avg=soma(sum)/20 
    return avg
print(average(avg))

def maxx(maxx):
    maxx=v[0] 
    for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
        if v[i+1]>v[i]:
            maxx=v[i+1]
        else:
            maxx=v[i]
    return maxx
print(maxx(maxx))


I expect the function to generate the maximum number in the list and not the last number as it is happening.


import random
v=[]
sum=0
avg=0
maxx=0
minn=0

def generate(v):
    for i in range(0,20): 
        x=random.randint(1,100) 
        v.append(x) 
    return v 
print(generate(v))

def soma(sum):
    for k in range(0,len(v)): 
        sum=sum+v[k]
    return sum

def average(avg):
    avg=soma(sum)/20 
    return avg
print(average(avg))

def maxx(maxx):
    maxx=v[0] 
    for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
        if v[i+1]>v[i]:
            maxx=v[i+1]
        else:
            maxx=v[i]
    return maxx
print(maxx(maxx))
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is input and what is the desired output versus the actual output?

Comment: sorry i post the cood two times. I would like to know what is wrong with my maxx function. It does not return the maximum value but the last value in array

Comment: `if v[i+1]>v[i]` – each element should be compared to the current maximum, not the element before it.

Comment: but for example for i =0 if v[1]>v[0] the maximum should be v[1] otherwise is v[0]. Why cant i do this

Comment: You are using the name `maxx` both for a function and a variable. Python does not differentiate these two things, so in `print(maxx(maxx))` you will be calling the function `maxx` with the function `maxx` itself as argument.

Comment: `maxx=v[0]` also overwrites whatever argument you passed to the function.

Comment: but even if i change the name it returns the last element, but yes you are right

Answer (score 4):

The way you have your `maxx` function set up you will only ever have the last or second last element of a list be the max.  Instead of comparing to `v[i]` you need to compare to your current max:

```
def maxx(maxx):
    maxx=v[0] 
    for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
        if v[i+1]>maxx:
            maxx=v[i+1]
    return maxx
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can improve your implementation including using `enumerate` to loop over list indices and items and using miningful name variables.

```
def maxx(_list):
    _max = -float("inf")
    for n in _list:
    # use for i,n in enumerate(_list): if you need i
        if n > _max:
            _max = n
    return _max
```

Comment: but what i understand with that is you are starting the max with a value lower to any element on the list. But with that function you are looping the list and you only comparing the current element with the max you set. However how do you know if the current element is not bigger ou lower than the element before it?

Comment: that is why i compare the current element v[j] with the following one v[j+1]

Comment: @Luismaia1994 You don't care if it's bigger than the one before it. All you care about is if it's bigger than the biggest one you've seen so far.

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()` if you never use `i`?

Comment: @Luismaia1994 Consider the list `[100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. After the 2nd element, each one is bigger than the one before it, but they're not the biggest.

Comment: i think i understand now. We set inicially tha maxx to a value we know is lower than all in the list. But as we iterate we compare the current element with the maxx. If the current element is higher than the maxx the current element becomes the maxx. Thanks all for the answers

Comment: The question at this point is not clear. Are you looking for an implementation of the `max()` function? or what? Looping using `enumerate()` is way better than looping over `range(0,len(v)-1)` in general, if you don't use `i` then you can simply iterate over the items of course.

Comment: I have a very primitive way of code implementation. I do not program in years. I only have 4 days of phyton. Sure there are ways of looping in a list better than the ones im implementing, but first i need to understand the simple ones

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(a_list)` is the simple one!

Comment: yes alec_djinn but that is a build up function. I'm trying to do simple programs but with the least build up functions possible